# Python conventions with respect to if conditions

Tags: python

**In python, is it frowned upon to use extra conditions within an if statement to avoid error, or should this be done separately from the if statement?**

Example:

I want to make sure that d, which will be either a empty string or a number string is not blank and not less than 1. If d is a empty string, it can not be converted to a float. The statement is evaluated as false before trying to convert to float so I don't get an error. Is this bad practice?

```
def main(): 
    d = "2.25"
    check_d(d)
    d = "0"
    check_d(d)
    d = ""
    check_d(d)
```

## this looks prettier to me

```
def check_d(d):
    if d and float(d) >= 1:
        return True
    print('d must be defined with value 1 or greater')
    return False
```

## this was my first instinct

```
def check_d_old(d):
    try:
        if float(d) >= 1:
            return True
    except:
        pass
    print('d must be defined with value 1 or greater')
    return False
```

Comment: For what it's worth, since you're not using the return value of check_d, why return anything in either case?  And if you *are* going to return something, why not return True or False (rather than 0 or 1).  Then your main driver can be `if not isAcceptable(d): print('d must be defined...'); return`.

Comment: You do not need the else statement if your if statement ends in a return.

Comment: If you are always certain that `d` will either be a blank string or a **valid** number representation then the first is fine, however if `d` could be anything else like `'a'` then the second is more robust.

Comment: Python has Boolean constants `True` and `False`; use them instead of 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `if d` part if you include it in the try. Something like this would work, where either you'll get a `ValueError` if it's not a number, or it'll raise a `ValueError` if it is a number but under 1.

```
def check_d(d):
    try:
        if float(d) >= 1:
            return 0
        else:
            raise ValueError()
    except ValueError:
        print('d must be defined with value 1 or greater')
        return 1
```

It's fine using extra conditions, but if you can skip a few unnecessary ones, it'll run faster overall. Also, try to not just use `except`, find out which type of error you want to be looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The first is fine assuming that `d` will always fit your criteria but the second example is more robust.

For example when `d = "a"` the condition `if d and float(d) >= 1:` will raise the `ValueError` where as the `try: except` will catch it and work properly.

So if your criteria of "d will be either a blank string or a number string" is absolute then the first is fine, however if `d` could have other values then you may want to use the second.

Comment: `assert` is removed if the code is compiled with `-O`; it's better to make an explicit check.

Comment: dang it, excuse me while I go fix some other code of mine that will malfunction with the `-O` flag. :(